# libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I am facing issue during compilation process where c library 'libc.so.6' is expecting GLIBC version as 2.25, I have glibc version as 2.23 as follows. Does that causing issue in my case?

Issue:-

```
gcc/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0/12.2.0/cc1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0/12.2.0/cc1)
```

my libc.so.6 shows glibc 2.23:-

```
krk@test-lnx44-11:~/debugs/working$ /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
GNU C Library (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu11.3) stable release version 2.23
```

GLIBC versions i could find in cc1 exe from gcc `12.2` version is :-

```
gcc/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0/12.2.0/cc1 | grep GLIBC
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.7
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.25
__GLIBCXX_BITSIZE_INT_N_%d=%d
__GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_%d=__int%d
```

GLIBC versions i could find in cc1 exe from gcc `8.3` version is :-

```
gcc/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.1.0/8.3.0/cc1 | grep GLIBC
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.14
__GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_%d=__int%d
__GLIBCXX_BITSIZE_INT_N_%d=%d
```

What does the above `strings` command output mean?

Basically, i am doing cross compilation where host is x86_64 and target is 'QNX aarch64'. I am planning to upgrade gcc toolchain to 12.2 and hits into above issue. With the older gcc version `8.3` compilation goes well.  Looks like newer version of gcc expects `glibc 2.25`. Are there any debug flags that helps to understand the cause of problem?

Comment: You seem to be cross-compiling for qnx aarch64. The version of your linux x86-64 library is utterly irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, My host machine is based out of x86_64 platform where i am trying to build for QNX aarch64. So in cross compilation for qnx aarch64, where do i need to check for glibc ?

Comment: Wherever your linker searches for it. Use -Wl,--verbose to find out.

Comment: Actually i am facing this issue at compilation stage where .o file gets created from .c file using command `usr/bin/qcc -v -V12.2.0,gcc_ntoaarch64le ...` , During compilation stage is there a way to debug? Any flags that helps here?

Comment: Oh sorry it seems you cannot *run* the compiler because it requires that version of glibc. This is a completely different story. I don't know how this could happen.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, regarding your first comment, To cross compile on host  x86_64 , we need the  binary (cc1) and its linked libraries (libc.so.6) is also has to be based out of x86_64 platform right? Otherwise it wont work. Let me know if i am missing anything here.

Comment: Yes you are right and I don't know how a lower version can be missing.

Comment: What does the `strings` command output above? Does that mean all GLIBC versions are supported or maximum GLIBC version is supported ? i.e. GLIBC 2.25 in case of gcc12.2 , So we should have atleast glibc2.25 and higher versions to be installed on the host?

Comment: After your edit: your compiler requires 2.25, you only have 2.23, that is, you have an older version than you need. So the error message is normal and expected. You need an upgrade to at least glibc 2.25, which normally only happens with an OS upgrade. Note 2.23 was released back in 2016, the current release is 2.39.

Comment: We cant do OS upgrade, Any other alternative to use newer version glibc ? Can install it as non default version and use it via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to access glibc 2.25 ?

Comment: glibc **is** your OS.